# How to transform and rotate the rectangles on partition layout in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I want to place rectangles inside partition layout with transform of arc position.
just like below image [image]

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rajagopal/pkENx/1/)

**D3.js**:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
             .data(node)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
             .attr("y", function (d) { return d.x + d.dx - 0.01 / (d.depth + 2.6); })
             .attr("width", 20)
             .attr("height", 100) 

             .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")rotate(" + ((2*Math.PI)+2.6*(d.x + d.dx))+ ")"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rect transform ,rotate need to `rotate(" + ((d.x + (d.dx / 2)) - Math.PI ) / Math.PI * 180 + ")"` instead of `rotate(" + ((d.x + (d.dx / 2)) - Math.PI/2 ) / Math.PI * 180 + ")"`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/6TSbv/)**

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
             .data(node)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
             .attr("y", function (d) { return d.x + d.dx - 0.01 / (d.depth + 2.6); })
             .attr("width", 20)
             .attr("height", 100) 

             .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")rotate(" + ((d.x + (d.dx / 2)) - Math.PI ) / Math.PI * 180 + ")"});
```